# Woocommerce menus on category pages

Tags: wordpress, menu, woocommerce

I'm creating a unique design for a Woocommerce webshop and I've run into a problem. I want the end-user to be able to add categories and also add custom menu's on those created pages. 
Any of you guys have a brilliant idea how to do that? I thought I would put the wp_title() of the page in a variable and put the code for a menu on my category page-template with that variable, but that doesn't seem to be the solution. Any brilliant thoughts?

Extra info: the reason why my own solution will never work, is because you can't register the menu in your functions.php with a variable name..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method of doing this would be to create the pages you need for your nav and then add the WooCommerce shortcode to the page.

[product_category category="example" per_page="12" columns="4" orderby="date" order="desc"]